# Integrated traffic server with apache sling

Tags: java, web, jcr, sling

I need a traffic server to cache page and manages request queue integrated with Apache Sling.
Could any body guide me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a HTTP proxy in front, you can easily use Apache or nginx for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need a light-weighted and simple traffic server. I think using Apache Traffic server is complicated. Do you know about a simpler one?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'traffic server'?

Comment: Apache Traffic Server is a tool to manage request, traffic and cache on servers see [link](http://trafficserver.apache.org/)

Comment: I know what 'Apache Traffic Server' is, but you mentioned that it's too complicated for you. What kind of tool are you looking for, if this one is too complicated?